# SCNNode (SCNCamera) rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, scenekit

I have an SCNView with SCNCamera and SCNNode being set.

Initially it looks like this:

[image]

While I would like it to look like this:

[image]

How can I set it to be initially in such rotation position? (with center of the SCNNode being located in the center of the view)

I have tried manipulation with '.position', '.pivot', '.rotation', etc... But without success.

Comment: Please show us the code that positions and rotates the target node and the camera node.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want to set the rotation directly, expressed in roll, pitch, and yaw:
Try

```
node.eulerAngles
```

For example in `SCNVector3Make(x,y,z)` x, y and z are described in radians.
Which means that one whole time around is `pi (3.141592653589793238462632795 or M_PI) x 2.0`.

So you may want to try rotating your node to `SCNVector3Make(0, M_PI / 2, M_PI / 4)`

Comment: It leads to same results as changing the '.pivot' property -- apart from rotation, it also changes the initial position of the node (i.e. initially the node is not in the center of SCNView, sometimes not even visible at all, being located far to the top/bottom/left/right).
Is it possible to change such behaviour?

Comment: Actually, yes, this is the correct solution. The problem was that I was trying to change '.eulerAngles' of my CameraNode, not the actual Node with graphics. Thanks for help